# the contradicted observation after installing python wheel library

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-wheel

I have installed wheel successfully as follows:

```
(py2.7) [abcd@cluster1830 ~]$ pip install /data/pythonlibs/wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /data/pythonlibs/wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: wheel
Found existing installation: wheel 0.30.0a0
  Uninstalling wheel-0.30.0a0:
  Successfully uninstalled wheel-0.30.0a0
  Successfully installed wheel-0.29.0
```

Then I tried to use the following command to check the installed libraries,

```
(py2.7) [abcd@cluster1830 ~]$ pip freeze > /data/dump.txt
```

Opening the dump.txt, I cannot find the installed wheel library,

```
(py2.7) [abcd@cluster1830 ~]$ cat /data/dump.txt
protobuf==3.1.0.post1
six==1.10.0
```

At the same time, I tried `import wheel` from `python`,

```
(py2.7) [abcd@cluster1830 ~]$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr 11 2017, 10:32:43)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wheel
>>>
```

Looks like it works, which confuses me. Whether I have wheel library installed or not?

During my installing tensorflow, I had the following error message,

```
 Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow-gpu==1.0.1)
 No distributions at all found for wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow-gpu==1.0.1)
```

Comment: Your user & host names changed in the fourth prompt.  Are you running all of these commands on the same server as the same user with the same version of Python?

Comment: Hi jwodder, thanks for pointing it out. I have updated. All of these commands were run on the same system.

Comment: Does the `wheels` module have some sort of `__version__` attribute, and if so, what does it print?

Comment: Hi tobias_k, with the commandline of print(wheel.__version__), I get 0.29.0